# If statement with db response

Tags: meteor, reactjs

OPENED A NEW ISSUES: [Meteor / ReactJS - UI blinking issue: rendering twice before and after checking a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194938/meteor-reactjs-issue-rendering-twice-before-and-after-checking-a-database)

NEW ISSUE has more detailed example

---

Meteor + ReactJS App: I need to check if a database (collection) already has a value and based on it decide what to show.

here is what I have:

```
render() {

    if (this.props.companies.length) {
        return (
          <div className="container">

            {this.renderCompanies()}

          </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
          <div className="container">

            <header id="addCompanyForm">
              <h1>Add Company</h1>

              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref="companyName"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Type a new company name"
                />
              </form>
            </header>

          </div>
        );
    }
  }
```

My problem: this.props.companies.length is 0, 0 and only third time it becomes 1 if I have a company in my collection already. Therefore, it shows the form the first second and then it hides it when it finally receives collection values and changes to company details. How can I remove that blink the first second and show a correct statement right away. I tried React lifecycles + sessions also and nothing helped.

Comment: Are you using [`createContainer`](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer) to fetch the data from the database?

Comment: Yes - createContainer(() => { ... }

Comment: Meteor and ReactJS are already indicated in the tags - no need to add them to the title.

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you have an ajax call taking place that is fetching all the companies and while this is happening companies.length is 0 which renders the form. Once the api response comes back, then companies is populated with information and the form goes away.

If it were me, I'd have a loading state when the api call is taking place and displaying some sort of placeholder that is showing that loading is happening and then when loading is done render the actual component that checks to see if there are companies and if there is render them otherwise show the form.

You don't have to make a third component you could do something like:

```
render() {
 // depending where the ajax call is happening would depict if this is a state or a prop for loading...
  if (this.props.loading) {
    return <div> Loading companies...</div>
  }

  // rest of your logic goes here for if companies.length
}
```

Comment: It didn't help, no difference. It doesn't actually even try to show loading div for a loading statement

Comment: Hi, I created another issue based on this with much more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194938/meteor-reactjs-issue-rendering-twice-before-and-after-checking-a-database