# Meteor / ReactJS - UI blinking issue: rendering twice before and after checking a database

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

Task: I need to show components based on a database result.
Issue: It renders components before it checks a database and shows a result without taking any info from a database and second time after it received a result from a database, which creates UI problem of blinking*

*in my example (...removed...) I show it. Once at least one task added refresh the page and the "Add Task!" red block will be visible for the first half a second.

How to fix that issue? Should I use "promise" or there is anything else I can do to show a result only after it checks a database?

Comment: That is partly because you are using autopublish. You don't have any means to determine whether or not the data is available. When you use a subscription, you can get its `ready()` state to determine if you should display some kind of "loading" state and when to render the actual component.

Comment: I left autopublish to simplify things, but even if I remove it, it won't make any difference.

ready() - this might be a solution, can you please provide more examples where I can look up for solutions?

Comment: What makes you think that it renders the component before it "checks the database"? On page load you have no data, it takes a (short) while for the data to arrive, and when it does, it re-fetches the data and renders again. See the examples for [createContainer()](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer) for reference.

Comment: The issue is: once a task is added and after refreshing a page it shows a red box again (based on my example) a first half of a second, which creates a blinking UI effect. I want to fix that. I want to show components ONLY after it receives all props (database result)

Comment: See the examples I linked to in my comment edit. Let me know if that helps and if you need some specific example.

Comment: I updated GitHub page with: autopublish+insecure were deleted and I also added ready() to createContainer(). File that most likely will be responsible for fixing this issue: https://github.com/dartem/meteor_react_issue_1/blob/master/ui/App.jsx. renderTasks() renders my if statement before loading in createContainer happens.

Comment: Great. Use the `loading` prop to render a temporary "loading" view.

Comment: Can you please be more specific how can loading help me to render my tasks only after database response was received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container subscribes to data and monitors the subscription's `ready` state:

```
createContainer(() => {
  const todosHandle = Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
  const loading = !todosHandle.ready();

  return {
    loading,
    tasks: Tasks.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

This means that you component will receive a boolean `loading` prop which indicates whether or not the data is available. You can use it in your component to render a `loading` view while the data is loading:

```
class App extends Component {
  //...
  render() {
    const {loading, tasks} = this.props;
    if (loading) {
      return (
        <div className="spinner">
          Loading...
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Todo List</h1>
        </header>
          //...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or any other combination of components that depends on the loading state.

BTW, the `tasks` prop is an array, so using `tasks.length` instead of `Object.keys` is likely better.